# Firestore first query

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to do my first query in firestone but I'm not able to see results properly. Could someone help me? Please take a look at the code and picture [image]

```
import UIKit
import Firestore
import Firebase

class ViewControllerFirestone: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

       simpleQueries()

    }

    private func simpleQueries() {

        let db = Firestore.firestore()


        let citiesRef = db.collection("cities")


        let myQuery = citiesRef.whereField("state", isEqualTo: "CA")

        print ("My query is retrieving this : \(myQuery)")


    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at the print at the botton of this picture:    https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRKzV.png

Answer (score 1):

After you construct your query, you have to then query the database--that's how you get data back. The data that's returned is a custom Firestore object (`QuerySnapshot`) that has a number of properties, one of which is `documents` which is an array of another custom Firebase object (`FIRDocumentSnapshot`). From that property is where your data resides. The `FIRDocumentSnapshot` object has a method called `get()` which can extract data for you (you can also use more idiomatic dictionary syntax and not use the `get()` method). Read the Firestore documentation online; it's often painfully terse but it works.

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseFirestore

class ViewControllerFirestone: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        simpleQueries()
    }

    private func simpleQueries() {

        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        let citiesRef = db.collection("cities")
        let myQuery = citiesRef.whereField("state", isEqualTo: "CA")

        myQuery.getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in

            guard let snapshot = snapshot,
                error == nil else { // error
                    return print("database error: \(error!)")
            }

            guard !snapshot.isEmpty else { // no data
                return print("no data")
            }

            // data fetched, loop through documents

            for doc in snapshot.documents {

                guard let stateProperty = doc.get("state") as? String else {
                    continue // continue loop
                }
                print(stateProperty)

            }

        }

    }

}
```

As a side note, this is a good place to use dispatch queues to handle your results in the background as the data returned by Firestore will always be on the main thread. This example does not use queues.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm gonna try! I'm starting as developer and I've choosen "swift language" with Firestone to develop my first app.

Comment: Sorry about the "firestone" lol  hahaha .  I'm trying here but without success... I've two questions:

1)  Inside the loop "for do in snapshot.documents{}"

The value of type 'DocumentSnapshot' has no member 'get' -> 
Thus this declaration " guard let stateProperty = doc.get("state")" is showing an error.

Any another suggestion of method? 

2) In this constant declaration: 

"guard !snapshot.isEmpty else { // no data
                return print("no data")
            }"

Why did you put "!" exclamation point before "snaptshot":

Comment: If you aren't having success with the above code, then there is something else wrong. Did you log into the Firebase Console, create a Firestore database, create a cities collection, and create that property? Also, did you add `import FirebaseFirestore` at the top of the file?

Comment: As to your other question, putting an `!` before a boolean property denotes that boolean as false. If you declared `let isBusy = false`, to then check if it's indeed false you could type `if !isBusy` or `if isBusy == false`.

Comment: Yes  I logged  into the Firebase Console, created a Firestore database and created a cities collection properly. I've also imported Firebase/Firestore at the top of the file. I put exactly as you suggested but the message /* Value of type 'DocumentSnapshot' has no member 'get' */ is displayed  in line which I write doc.get.

Please take a look and let me know if I did something wrong https://github.com/luissantosbh/fisiofinder.git.

Comment: Like I said, you need to import `FirebaseFirestore`. You imported `Firestore` and `Firebase`. Importing just `Firestore` should give you an error, that's not a valid module. Get rid of `import Firebase` and `import Firestore` and just declare `import FirebaseFirestore`. I updated my answer to show you what to import. Don't import modules, like `Firebase`, that you don't need.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!!!  It worked as a charm!!! In addiction I needed to changed my pod file too. Again... Thank you!!!!